How can I obtain the corrected image after performing perspective correction and cropping?
I have finished a logic to correct the perspective and crop an image using a draggable overlay.
The image is probably larger or smaller than the view size, and it is scaled to fit the view size and centered in the middle. The function correctPerspectiveAndCropImage tries to correct the perspective and crop the image according to the points received, but the resulting image always has incorrect coordinates or size.

Here is the main persent logic:
private func correctPerspectiveAndCropImage(
  image: UIImage, topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint,
  in geometry: GeometryProxy
) -> UIImage? {
  print("Correcting perspective")
  print("TopLeft: \(topLeft), TopRight: \(topRight), BottomLeft: \(bottomLeft), BottomRight: \(bottomRight)")

  // Ensure the image can be converted to CIImage
  guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }
  let viewSize = geometry.size
  let imageSize = image.size

  // Calculate aspect ratios
  let imageAspect = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
  let viewAspect = viewSize.width / viewSize.height

  var scale: CGFloat
  var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
  var offsetY: CGFloat = 0

  if imageAspect > viewAspect {
    // Image is wider: scale based on height
    scale = viewSize.height / imageSize.height
    offsetX = (viewSize.width - imageSize.width * scale) / 2
  } else {
    // Image is taller: scale based on width
    scale = viewSize.width / imageSize.width
    offsetY = (viewSize.height - imageSize.height * scale) / 2
  }

  // Convert points from view coordinates to image coordinates
  func convertPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let x = (point.x - offsetX) / scale
    let y = (viewSize.height - point.y - offsetY) / scale
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
  }

  // Convert points to image coordinates
  let tl = convertPoint(topLeft)
  let tr = convertPoint(topRight)
  let bl = convertPoint(bottomLeft)
  let br = convertPoint(bottomRight)

  // Create perspective correction filter
  guard let perspectiveCorrection = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection") else { return nil }
  perspectiveCorrection.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
  perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: tl), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
  perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: tr), forKey: "inputTopRight")
  perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: bl), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
  perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: br), forKey: "inputBottomRight")

  // Get the corrected image
  guard let correctedImage = perspectiveCorrection.outputImage else { return nil }

  // Create CGImage from corrected CIImage
  let context = CIContext(options: nil)
  guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(correctedImage, from: correctedImage.extent) else {
    return nil
  }

  // Return the corrected UIImage with the same orientation as the original image
  return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
}

I have checked the geometry passed through views, analyzed the code logic using AI tools and moved all views into one struct in order to prevent geometry size difference.
I want to obtain the corrected image after performing perspective correction and cropping.
